# Making subfolders in a resource folder

Tags: android

Is it possible to make subfolders in the resource folders in the Android project? I have about 200 images (thumbnails) that I need in my project and I could add them in the drawable-mdpi, but it would be better to not mix these images with the other ones. Something like drawable-mdpi --> thumbs --> all images here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No this is not allowed. You are only allowed to make folders specified by the android documentation.

The allowed sub folder names are specified in the [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html). Android generates the R.java based on these structures and putting sub folders can cause errors.

Answer (score 0):

actually, there are mechanisms in place that allow the `R.java` file to be generated when there are folders with non-standard names in the res folder.

(i ran into this wanting to share a git repo as a submodule of both an iOS and Android project, but not wantint the Android project to pick up files that resided in a folder i designated.)

`aapt` is the tool that creates the `R.java` file, and it can be invoked with the --ignore-assets argument.  there is a set of defaults for this found in the [google source documentation](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/98b631c6b3765be96b3707ba7aa54d52b10f4872/files/ant/build.xml), or a less verbose description simply by invoking `aapt` from the command-line without any arguments (or `--help`, which isn't a valid argument, but presents help nevertheless).  using the line `aapt.ignore.assets=xxx` in an `ant.properties` file in your Android project will accomplish pretty much the same thing, depending upon your needs or preferences.

if you do not have a `build.xml` or other mechanism that forces usage of `ant` (which i do not), one of the `aapt` `--ignore-assets` defaults is `<dir>_*`, which means ignore any folders starting with `_`.

this was my fallback:  i created a directory called `_iOS_retina` and placed all of my @2x files in there.  (in Xcode, i can simply pull in resources from wherever they reside).  the default invocation of `aapt` simply ignores it.  to further streamline my project, i also updated my `.project` file to contain a resource filter that ignores this folder, and thus it doesn't take any space in my eclipse environment, either.

```
    <filteredResources>
        <filter>
            <id>1371429105277</id>
            <name></name>
            <type>26</type>
            <matcher>
                <id>org.eclipse.ui.ide.multiFilter</id>
                <arguments>1.0-name-matches-true-false-_iOS_retina</arguments>
            </matcher>
        </filter>
    </filteredResources>
```